# How do I add a button and label to my frame?

Tags: jframe, jbutton, jlabel

Ok basically my problem is I don't know how to get my buttons and my labels to appear in the frame that I just created. I tried using frame.add(new JButton("VOTE1")); but that doesn't work and it says it's missing an identifier. Here is my code so far, your help is much appreciated.

```
  import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class VotingMachine extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          JFrame frame = new JFrame("Voting Machine");
          frame.setSize(400, 300);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       }


       private JLabel Candidate1 = new JLabel("My Name");
       private JLabel Candidate2 = new JLabel("Jennifer Lawrence");
       private JLabel Candidate3 = new JLabel("Cristiano Ronaldo");

       private JButton VOTE1 = new JButton("VOTE FOR Bishoy Morcos");
       private JButton VOTE2 = new JButton("VOTE FOR Jennifer Lawrence");
       private JButton VOTE3 = new JButton("VOTE FOR Cristiano Ronaldo");

       int countcandidate1;
       int countcandidate2;
       int countcandidate3;


       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          Object o = e.getSource();
          if(o == VOTE1)
             countcandidate1++;
          else if(o == VOTE2)
             countcandidate2++;
          else if(o == VOTE3)
             countcandidate3++;
          }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a JPanel

```
JPanel welcomePanel = new JPanel();
```

Then add the buttons and labels to that panel

```
welcomePanel.add(Candidate1);
welcomePanel.add(VOTE1);
```

ETC.... for all of your buttons and labels

Lastly, add that JPanel to your JFrame

```
frame.add(welcomePanel);
```

If this answers your question, please mark it as answered so other viewers will be informed.

Comment: thank you it did help i was able to make the panel however when i try to add the buttons and labels to the panel i get an error saying an identifier is expected between add X (Candidate1);